# What is the recommended FDQN for a local laptop on a DHCP home network?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, dhcp

I have a pretty common home network and a laptop that connects to it either by Ethernet or wifi and gets an IP using DHCP. What is the recommended configuration for FDQN, including hostname and /etc/hosts? I currently have

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    euclides.localdomain euclides
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

and on /etc/hostname:

```
euclides.localdomain
```

I would like to configure it to keep everything in the local network working the way it is now and try to prevent errors like this one from Spark:

```
18/01/15 08:12:25 WARN Utils: Your hostname, euclides.localdomain resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.22 instead (on interface enp3s0)
```

Comment: Apparently whatever you used doesn't like using local addresses and especially unusual ones. In addition even if it's using your network interface ip the OS and drivers should recognize that you're talking to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So the message is warning you that euclides.localdomain resolvbes to 127.0.1.1
and yes your hostfile does resolve euclides.localdomain  to 127.0.1.1

```
127.0.1.1    euclides.localdomain euclides
```

so the host file should say

```
192.168.0.22  euclides.localdomain euclides
```

However its DHCP so the DHCP server assigns an address - so in that case the host file should not have this line at all

```
# 127.0.1.1    euclides.localdomain euclides
```

That sort of partially answers your question - the host file should not have euclides.localdomain  resolving to a local address.  I do agree that I did not think this was a requirement  howevver my company uses hosts files a lot , we copy a single copy between all machines , so I've never seen a host name resolve to the loopback address , only loopback resolves to the loopback IP, a hostname 
always resolves to a non-loopback IP

What you need is either the DHCP server to update a DNS server with the DHCP lease updates ( I say this as this is what I have with a raspberry PI running DNSMASQ) OR the euclides.localdomain  needs to do a dynamic update of the DNS server, this is what Windows Server does but no 8.8.8.8 will not accept an update from you.

Alternatively you could create a DHCP reservation and then manually edit the hosts file.  This is a bit of a fudge as Hosts is really for static addresses 
DHCP reservations still creates a DHCP Lease and so still works with DNSMASQ

A laptop running windows may be using the Netbios name resolution service - which does local broadcasts or uses WINS servers  - both are bit old , I believe deprecated in favor of DDNS.  Again though the hosts file should still not contain entries for hosts with DHCP assigned addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the logic behind this warning is as follows:

1. An FQDN implies there is "the domain", and
2. Being a part of a domain implies having a non-local unique address on some network.

Suposedly the `localhost.localdomain` is treated specially
(even though AFAIK there's no RFC or something which would give the `localdomain` NIS domain name any special treatment).

On my networks, I use `.lan` as the root domain name,
so I'd configure something like `home.lan` on your DHCP/DNS server.

Comment: Thanks. The big issue is that my DHCP server is my modem/router for broadband and my DNS server is Google (8.8.8.8), so `.lan` or `.localdomain` are equivalent. A RFC for this setup, that is quite common, would be very helpful, but I was not able to find one myself too.

Comment: The question is: do you have other machines on your LAN, which you'd like to talk to each other using hostnames?